# symfony add more field to BadRequestException

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Currently, BadReqeustException return json like this when I have error.

```
{
   "code": 400,
   "message": "missing parameter: myField"
}
```

Because i'm using this code

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException("missing parameter: $param");
```

But I want add more field to exception

```
{
   "code": 400,
   "missing_filed": myField
   "message": "missing parameter"
}
```

And I don't know how to add and return it like this format.

Answer (score 2):

If you throw the BadRequestHttpException yourself you can simply extends your new Exception class with an extra field from BadRequestHttpException.

```
namespace AppBundle\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

class MyBadRequestHttpException extends BadRequestHttpException {

    public $missingFiled;

    public function __construct($message = null, $missingFiled = null, \Exception $previous = null, $code = 0) {
        parent::__construct($message, $previous, $code);
        $this->missingFiled = $missingFiled;
    }

}
```

And where ever you want to throw the exception use code like this:

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException("missing parameter", $param);
```

You can also read more about extending Exception [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

Comment: I did like you, but still return 

{'code': 400, 'message': 'missing parameter'}, still can pass missingField to acception

Comment: @vibol do you defined your $missingFiled property as public? which package do you use for serializing? (jms serializer or symfony serializer or ...)

Comment: I'm decare $missingField as public and using jms serializer

Comment: @vibol Did you use `@Expose` for your field? [Annotations](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations)

Comment: I didn't use @Expose for my field. could you give me full namspace?

Comment: @vibol the Full namespace is \JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose